# Override Wordpress Url Rewriting

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to override wordpress url rewriting for 1 specific file. My current wordpress install rewrites .html files to the according .php extension. So, for a permalink in MY wordpress installation might look like www.mysite.com/mypage.html.

I have an ACTUAL HTML file i want to show, however the htaccess keeps auto rewriting it by default, here is the code i'm trying to use to IGNORE this specific file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forex-system-demo\.html$ [NC] #<-- This is the file i want to ignore and run as a NORMAL .HTML file
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I may have had some wierd browser caching going on because what is below now works after clearing cache.

**Here is the SOLUTION:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^forex-system-demo.html$ - [L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the offending line first?

Comment: What are the file permissions on the HTML? The line 'RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f' should be checking if it's an actual file. If Apache doesn't have read permission, it might not 'see' the file.

Comment: Hi Justin, it appears there are read permissions -looks like it says 644

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the SOLUTION:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^forex-system-demo.html$ - [L] # <- this is where I tell wordpress to ignore this url
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```